# Program to add n integers not working in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int n,c,value,sum=0;
    printf ("Enter the no of integers u want to add:");
    scanf ("%d",&n);
    printf ("\nEnter %d integers:",n);
    for (c=1;c<=n;c++)
    {
        scanf ("%d",&value);
        sum=sum+value;
    }
    printf ("\nSum of the integers:%d",sum);
    getch();
}
```

The program is giving different outputs as the sum. I cannot find out the fallacy. Help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Give an example of the output you're getting, and explain why you think it's wrong.

Comment: Give an example of the *input* you're using.

Comment: Also, why are you calling `getch()` at the end and not assigning it to anything?

Comment: @JackManey To prevent the console window from closing, probably.

Comment: @JackManey Probably he use some bad IDE, and wants that the terminal will not auto-close at the end of the program.

Comment: @DanielFischer and asaelr- Ah, you're probably right.  I'm so used to calling my programs from a CLI that the idea didn't even occur to me...

Comment: Works fine here, only change I made was replacing `getch` with `getchar` so it would compile as it is above.

Comment: I replaced `getch();` with `return 0;` and it works fine here too.

Comment: Also do not put a space between function calls and their `(`

Comment: Thanks for your responses.
I guess I have sorted out the problem.

Comment: I suggest looping from `0` to `< n` instead of from `1` to `<= n`.

Answer (score 1):

There's something else wrong with your setup that's not shown here.

The following code works fine (once you get rid of that non-standard `getch()` abomination and return a value from `main`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int n,c,value,sum=0;
    printf ("Enter the no of integers u want to add:");
    scanf ("%d",&n);
    printf ("Enter %d integers:",n);
    for (c=1;c<=n;c++) {
        scanf ("%d",&value);
        sum=sum+value;
    }
    printf ("Sum of the integers:%d\n",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

The transcript:

```
pax> ./qq
Enter the no of integers u want to add:3
Enter 3 integers:1 2 3
Sum of the integers:6

pax> ./qq
Enter the no of integers u want to add:5
Enter 5 integers:10
20
30
40
50
Sum of the integers:150
```